# Visual explanation of forecasting algorithm

Tags: forecasting, intuition, interactive-visualization

I am trying to develop the concept to give an intuitive explanation of how my forecasting algorithm works.

The forecasting algorithm uses historic data and some current-day data to forecast the remaining work for the day as it is a workforce planning algorithm. It does not contain any big datasets and only a few input parameters such as number of incoming documents, number of workers etc. The forecasting is just for one day.

I am not sure what visualization technique I can use in such a scenario. I have tried to use a line graph with mouse-over but the users are not able to understand the shape of the graph. They want to understand how the rules of the forecasting algorithm affect the graph shape.

My question is: what visualization technique can I use to make it more intuitive, so that I can explain how different rules affect the graph shape and also make them interact with the technique?

Answer (score 1):

Since the amount of time required to deaal with incoming work may be dependent on the existing amount of work or memory in the arrival of older work , one might want to quantify that. Unusual values or regime shifts(level shifts) might be needed to be identified and incorprated. Furthermore certain hoyrs of the day may have unique profiles based upon historical data.

Comment: Thanks for the information.I got your point. But I am not really sure how to make user visualize these regime shifts. And yes ofcourse certain hours of the day have unique profiles such that when day start, most of the time incoming documents are more.
I am still not sure how to visualize such scenarios to the user.